# Bedeutung der Aussage im Song verstehen

Tags: lyrics

Im [Lied von Cassandra Steen](http://www.songtexte.com/songtext/cassandra-steen/stadt-23f0cc87.html) heisst es:

> Ich bau' 'ne Stadt für dich
>   Aus Glas und Gold und Stein
>   Und jede Straße die hinausführt
>   Führt auch wieder rein
>   Ich bau' eine Stadt für dich und für mich.

Nun wie ist die Sache mit der Stadt zu verstehen?

- Dass es sich um eine Tochter eines Bauunternehmen-Milliardärs handelt, schliesse ich schon mal aus.
- Etwas bezogen auf die Beziehung? Sie würde z.B. keine Trennung zulassen durch Aufbau einer engen Bindung, wie eine Stadt ohne Ein- und Ausgang? Aber geht da nicht etwas Romantik verloren?

Comment: Hier wird *Stadt* im übertragenen Sinn verwendet. Übertragene Bedeutungen sind in der Lyrik häufig, aber keinesfalls auf die deutsche Sprache begrenzt: *we built this city, we built this city on rock an' roll*. Die Interpretation einer solchen Passage ist naturgemäß subjektiv. Um dennoch eine "korrekte" und möglichst nicht subjektive Antwort zu ermöglichen, müßtest Du Deine Frage umformulieren, bzw. etwas mehr eingrenzen.